# How to parse atom feeds in php?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I had tried to parse atom feeds from crunch board website using simplex ml_load_file function but I couldn't parse .  feed URL-  http://www.crunchboard.com/crunchboard.atom      please help me out

Comment: _"but I couldn't parse"_. Do you get an error?

Comment: Not getting error,Getting a  blank page